# Are questions about economical cooking welcome here?

Tags: support, scope

By economical cooking, I am thinking about utensils, cookwares, stoves, ovens, electricity and gas consumption, etc... - the cheapest good quality stuff.

I am also talking about cooking methods that will consume least amount of energy and time.

Are questions of this sort allowed here?

Comment: That is, you can ask about whatever style of cooking you like - the restrictions are on the kind of question, not the kind of cooking (as Aaronut mentions). If there's something that made this unclear, let us know!

Answer (score 6):

Sure, that's what the [budget-cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/budget-cooking) tag is for.

Please do note, however, that all of the usual expectations around specificity and constructiveness still apply. So questions of the form *recommend me some cheap meal ideas/restaurants* will be closed, not because they are off-topic but because they are polls.

I point out the above because the budget-cooking tag historically [attracted these types of questions](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/12218/41) and we had to delete a lot of them (keeping one or two, such as the one above, for historical reference). As long as the questions are reasonably specific, they're welcome here.